# Copy of Database catilog from one instance to another using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've been searching all over for an example of doing this but I'm not finding it.  I know it is possible because we had it working at one point but the resource that developed the process isn't currently available to fix the process which is currently corrupted beyond repair. In fact corrupted so badly we can't even get into take a look at what was there to build a copy of the process over again.

What we have is a 'Production_DB' and a 'Test_DB' which and the two are essentially the same. What was taking place is that a SSIS task was firing at the end of each work day and refreshing 'Test_DB' with the data that is in 'Production_DB'.  In this way testing can take place and changed can be made to the test bed without any concern that it will get too far afield of the live data because each evening this data is brought back to exactly what is in production. Meanwhile for testing purposes all testing is begin measure against actual real life data examples so when processes are pointed at the production data set there is less chance of issues.

The problem we have is several months back we didn't realize it but the SSIS package and source files became corrupted beyond readability. So, now we are looking for a way to replace the package to restore the process, but as of yet I have not been able to find an example that I can use to build from.

We are on SQL Server 2008 R2.

If anyone has some references they can point me to it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Schedule a backup restoral from the regular nightly backups.

Comment: I would recommend using powershell script instead, using DBATOOLS (https://dbatools.io/) It's free and community supported and it does a better and faster job than SSIS package. You just give it few parameters and voila!

Comment: @PollusB Would you have a reference to point me to as an example I could use?  I'm not familiar with doing much at all with powershell.

Comment: Take a look at the videos https://dbatools.io/getting-started/ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-gN_kU4xzw. It will give you a hint on how easy that is. When you are ready to try it out, download it and try with a dev instance. In very short, powershell is a bit like DOS cmd merged with SSH and C shell in UNIX. Now you might not be familiar with any of these technologies but typing commands is not a bad thing when you are trying to automate and schedule. There are plenty of starters guide on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of tables and the SQL Server version you can use the import export wizard to identify prod as the source and test as the destination...use that wizard to create a task and SAVE the ending task (it should save as an SSIS package I believe). This will get you a quick way of making the SSIS package to copy the data over and you can even overwrite the destination data if you would like.

Right click the database > tasks > import data

Comment: Added SQL server version in post.

Comment: In the 2008 studio it didn't drop me into a Wizard but I'm in a Analysis Services Project I created. I've set up two data source (source and destination)  but seem to be having some hurdles getting around errors as I select "Data Source Views" to copy over.  Looks like permissions but that doesn't seem likely with my service account having full rights to the db's.